# C - g_snprintf works in one scenario but not in another

Tags: c, glib

Pretty simple situation.

I have a `response` pointer to struct and i want to populate its values.

In one palce it's working:

```
janus_audiobridge_sync_endpoint_response *response = g_malloc0(sizeof(janus_audiobridge_sync_endpoint_response));
response->error_code = JANUS_AUDIOBRIDGE_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
g_snprintf(response->error_cause, 512, "%s - %s", "Failed to find about page with locale - ", locale_text);
return response;
```

However when i do basicly the same thing another method, the `response->error_cause` turns out to be `null`:

```
janus_audiobridge_sync_endpoint_response *response = g_malloc0(sizeof(janus_audiobridge_sync_endpoint_response));
response->error_code = 0;
response->error_code = JANUS_AUDIOBRIDGE_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED;
g_snprintf(response->error_cause, 512, "You need to pass a valid user_secret, before you continue.");
goto plugin_response;
```

My question: Why does it work in one context and not another? What is the best Practive in C, to do this kind of stuff?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** And even weirder is that when i do:

```
response->error_cause = "You need to pass a valid user_secret, before you continue.";
```

It works on the second example, why is that?

**EDIT:**

As requested:

```
typedef struct janus_audiobridge_sync_endpoint_response {
    gint error_code;
    gchar *error_cause;
    json_t *message;
} janus_audiobridge_sync_endpoint_response;
```

Comment: Show the definition of `janus_audiobridge_sync_endpoint_response`; and possibly a [MCVE].

Comment: @Evert Hey Evert! I updated my question.

Comment: So, if you place a breakpoint on `goto plugin_response`, `response->error_cause` is null right there?

Comment: When i try to LOG the `response->error_cause` right under the `g_snprintf(response...` line. Its null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clear from the declaration that `error_cause` is just a pointer, not an array.

So it won't point at anything valid when you allocate (and clear) an instance of `janus_audiobridge_sync_endpoint_response`. Thus you get undefined behavior.

To fix this, you need to allocate room for the string. In glib-land, you can use the nice [`g_strdup_printf()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf) function for this:

```
response->error_cause = g_strdup_printf("%s - %s", "Failed to find about page with locale - ", "foo", locale_text);
```

Note that I added a `foo` to that call, your original code seems to fail to provide the proper number of arguments considering the format string, which (again!) gives you undefined behavior.

Doing e.g. `error_cause = "hello";` is always kind of safe, since that just sets the pointer in the struct to point at a static array somewhere in memory, it doesn't copy any characters. The only risk with that is that since the pointer in the struct is not `const`, somebody might try to modify the string which again would bring undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't think i understand. Why does it work in the first example then? And what is the solution?

Comment: @IvRRimUm: it works by accident the first time, the pointer is not pointing to an allocated buffer.

Comment: @IvRRimUm It doesn't "work", it just fails to fail in a manner that you notice. Undefined behavior is undefined, it might do the exact thing you expect but still be wrong.

Comment: Another question. Why do i have to allocate memory in one case and not in the direct assignment?

Comment: @IvRRimUm I did cover that, see the final paragraph.